# Making deb with bzr: QApplication dependency

Tags: package-management, dependencies, qt, bazaar

I'm trying to package a Qt 5.x application as described in https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html
My Build-Depends in `debian/control` file are:
`debhelper-compat (= 13), libqt5widgets5 (>=5.4), libqt5xml5 (>=5.4), libqt5gui5 (>=5.4), libqt5core5a (>=5.4), libtiff5 (>=4.0.3), libjpeg8 (>=8c), libgcc1 (>=1.3.0), libc6 (>=2.14), libpng16-16 (>=1.6.2-1), libstdc++6 (>=5.2)`
I'm building deb with `bzr builddeb -- -us -uc`

Unfortunately build process fails bcs it tries to launch test cases after binary compilation and one of them is crashing. The test case uses `QPainter` that requires an instance of `QApplication` to work. And it seems app crashes at creation of `QApplication`. The output is:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa, dxcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

So my guess is that bzr is trying to run the app in some clean environment that is made based on my Build-Depends list. And this list misses something that's required by `qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so`.

The question is: what can it be and how to track this down?
I can execute `ldd` on my machine, but i need it in bzr environment.

Here is the build log https://pastebin.com/BVbZVwr6 I've cut out a middle of compilation process to fit the paste size limits. But compilation is fine, It's make test that fails. The code of tests is here: https://cutt.ly/BgYQITO

Comment: Could you share the full log of `bzr builddeb -- -us -uc` to http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Here it is https://pastebin.com/BVbZVwr6   I've cut out a middle of compilation process to fit the paste size limits. But compilation is fine, It's `make test` that fails. The code of tests is here: https://cutt.ly/BgYQITO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The building environment is the minimum clean one which does not have a Display Server (X11, Wayland). Qt seems to fail detecting a display server.

I suspect those image tests launch some tools that required some desktop features.

Because this is the initial try to package.

- Enable the packaging debug using: `export DH_VERBOSE=1` at top of `debian/rules` file.
- Override DebHelper test step to skip it till you get you get some results then fix it later. Using an empty `override_dh_auto_test:`

Reference: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#rules

If you get it through, try enable tests that don't require server first. For full tests with display server, honestly I lack the experience, I didn't face such case before. Either all packages disable that or there is a solution which I didn't notice.